# motivation behind the spectral theorem in infinite dimensional Hilbert space

Tags: spectral-theory

why in spectral theory , spectral subspaces are viewed as the span of the generalized eigenvectors (, roughly speaking the generalized eigenvectors as i have understood are kind of eigenvectors of an operator although they don't belong to the Hilbert space on which the operator act. ) 
I have been reading Quantum Theory for Mathematicians by Brian ,i will quote what he said hooping to make my question more clear .

note : my question dealt with proposition 5 in Brian's quote

Given a bounded (for now) self-adjoint operator A, we hope to associate
with each Borel set E ⊂ σ(A) a closed subspace V E of H, where we think
intuitively that V E is the closed span of the generalized eigenvectors for A
with eigenvalues in E. [We could do this more generally for any E ⊂ R,
but we do not expect any contribution from R\σ(A).] We would expect the
collection of these subspaces to have the following properties.
1. V σ(A) = H and V ∅ = {0}.
2. If E and F are disjoint, then V E ⊥ V F .
3. For any E and F , V E∩F = V E ∩ V F .
4. If E 1 , E 2 , . . . are disjoint and E = ∪ j E j , then
V E =
V E j .
j
5. For any E, V E is invariant under A.
6. If E ⊂ [λ 0 − ε, λ 0 + ε] and ψ ∈ V E , then
(A − λ 0 I)ψ ≤ ε ψ .
The condition V σ(A) = H captures the idea that our generalized eigenvec-
tors should span H, while Property 2 captures the idea that our generalized
eigenvectors should have some sort of orthogonality for distinct eigenval-
ues, even if they are not actually in the Hilbert space. In Property 4, there
may be infinitely many of the E j ’s, in which case, the direct sum is in the
Hilbert space sense (Definition A.45). Properties 5 and 6 capture the idea
that V E is made up of generalized eigenvectors for A with eigenvalues in E.

Comment: It would help to render this in MathJax:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference . Also I seem to recall that Hall says a lot about motivation: what do you think is insufficient in his account?

Comment: I haven't understand Hall's statement :   Properties 5 and 6 capture the idea that V E is made up of generalized eigenvectors for A with eigenvalues in E. thank you for your advice